# R package ReporteRs: how to let it show cell padding in generated .docx documents?

Tags: r, reporters

I have been using the excellent R package ReporteRs for a while now for my R tables and plots. David Gohel did a wonderful job here ([David's site](http://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/word.html)).

The problem that I am encountering is that can't make the padding function within table cells work.

Here is a part of my code:

```
headerCellProp = cellProperties(background.color="#ffffff",border.bottom.width = 1, border.top.width = 1, border.left.width = 0, border.right.width = 0)
              headerTextProp = textProperties(font.weight="bold", color = "#000000", font.size=9 )
              dataCellProp = cellProperties(border.bottom.width = 0, border.top.width = 0, border.left.width = 0, border.right.width = 0)
              dataTextProp = textProperties(font.size=9, color = "#000000")
              dataParProp = parProperties(padding.top = 0, padding.bottom = 0, padding.left = 10, padding.right = 5, text.align = "right")
              footerCellProp = cellProperties(background.color="#ffffff",border.bottom.width = 0, border.top.width = 1, border.left.width = 0, border.right.width = 0)


    mfMyDataFrame = FlexTable( data = MyDataFrame
                                 , header.columns = FALSE
                                 , row.names = FALSE
                                 , cell_format = dataCellProp
                                 , text_format = dataTextProp
          )
          .names = names(MyDataFrame)
          headerRow = FlexRow(.names, textProp = headerTextProp, cellProp = headerCellProp )
          mfMyDataFrame = addHeaderRow( mfMyDataFrame, headerRow)
          footerRow = FlexRow()
          footerRow[1] = FlexCell( pot( " ", format = headerTextProp ), cellProp = footerCellProp, colspan = length(.names) )
          mfMyDataFrame = addFooterRow( mfMyDataFrame, footerRow)
          mfMyDataFrame[,] = parProperties( padding.top = 0, padding.bottom = 0, padding.left = 10, padding.right = 5, text.align = "right" )

          doc = addTitle( doc, "Table title", level = 4, stylename= "rTableLegend")
         doc = addFlexTable(doc, mfMyDataFrame)
```

The output .docx file doesn't show any padding in the table cells (no 10 left, no 5 right). Am I missing something here?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the author, David Gohel:

This was asked also on github there:
https://github.com/davidgohel/ReporteRs/issues/10
It was a minor bug solved since the version 0.5.3.

Here is code that applies to cell padding:

options( "ReporteRs-fontsize" = 9 )
dataParProp = parProperties(padding.top = 0, padding.bottom = 0, padding.left = 10, padding.right = 5, text.align = "right")

mfMyDataFrame = FlexTable( data = iris, body.par.props = dataParProp, header.par.props = dataParProp )

mfMyDataFrame = setFlexTableBorders( mfMyDataFrame, inner.vertical = borderProperties( style = "none" )
  , inner.horizontal = borderProperties( style = "none" ), outer.vertical = borderProperties( style = "none" ) )

Comment: Thanks David! First i tried to remove this question because it happened to be a bug. But it's much better this way.